# How to insert data into oracle database table using PL SQL which includes 365 days of the year

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I already have a table built in oracle. I'm trying to insert some data that looks like this:

[image: I want the data to look like this]

But, I can't seem to be able to add the DATE together with the ID, YEAR and INDICATOR.

I manage to get the DATE from 1/1/2019 7:00:00 PM - 12/31/2019 7:00:00 PM.

[image: Example of only date]

CODE:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(DATE)
select to_date('01-01-2019 7:00:00 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') + rownum -1 dt from dual 
connect by level <= to_date('05-01-2019 7:00:00 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') - 
                    to_date('01-01-2019 7:00:00 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') + 1;
```

When I exclude DATE, it looks like this:

[image: Example of ID, YEAR and INDICATOR]

CODE:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, YEAR, INDICATOR)
Values (sequ.nextval, '2019', 'X') ;
```

I tried to combine the two codes but it doesn't work. Is there any other ways I can do to make it works? Or I'm doing it the wrong way? 
The only change data is the DATE because I need it to be 365 days of 2019.
YEAR and INDICATOR remain the same for all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even shorter (assuming you can calculate your current year):

```
insert into table( id, date, year, indicator) 
    select sequ.nextval, to_date('31-12-2018 07:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + rownum, 2019, 'X' from all_objects where rownum <= 365
```

Or, if you prefer not to use the ALL_OBJECTS table:

```
insert into table( id, date, year, indicator) 
    select sequ.nextval, to_date('31-12-2018 07:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level, 2019, 'X' from dual connect by level <= 365
```

Comment: I tried both but it came out as error --> ORA-00913: too many values. What does it means by that?

Comment: to many values: insert into table (......) are the columns correct? you can´t insert wrong number of columns

Comment: Try the statement "select sequ.nextval, to_date('31-12-2018 07:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level, 2019, 'X' from dual connect by level <= 365" you should see 365 records

Comment: Having 365 hard-coded might be an issue if this is run again for next year... you could get the year number and the number of days from `sysdate` though.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked something. Thank you for your help. It works. @nabuchodonossor

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @AlexPoole

Comment: Hi if it works, please also accept answer (it´s part of the business here)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into table(id, "date", "year", indicator)
    select rownum, dt, extract(year from dt), 'X'
    from (select to_date('01-01-2019 7:00:00 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') + rownum - 1 as dt
          from dual 
          connect by level <= to_date('05-01-2019 7:00:00 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') - 
                        to_date('01-01-2019 7:00:00 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') + 1
         ) t;
```

Comment: I tried something similar before, but it doesn't work. The code you given me consists of error stating that ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier. What does it means?

Comment: @prestan - it means this isn't quite valid Oracle syntax *8-) Change `year(dt)` to `extract(year from dt)`, or a fixed value of course - getting the years from the dates is more elegant (if repetitive) particularly if the real query bases the date range on the current date instead of having that hard-coded.