# Insert data into oracle table using PL SQL only consists of 'Saturday' of the year

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have trouble inserting date data into table that only consists of 'Saturday'.
This is what I have:

```
  with dts as (
  select date'2015-01-01'+rownum-1 dt from dual
  connect by level <= 366
  )

  select * from dts
  where  to_char(dt, 'fmday') = 'saturday';
```

The output is only the date of 'Saturday' of the year 2015. It is what I want, but I'm quite lost when I tried to insert it into table.
It is something similar with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886012/how-to-insert-data-into-oracle-database-table-using-pl-sql-which-includes-365-da), the only difference is that I only need it to be on 'Saturday'.

Example code that I tried to edit from:

```
insert into table( id, date, year, indicator) 
select sequ.nextval, to_date('31-12-2018 07:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level, 2019, 'X' from dual connect by level <= 365
```

The date part is where I have trouble with.

Comment: Thanks prestan.  The insert provided is different from the only-saturday date-generator.  Have you tried to run the insert by including the id NEXTVAL, "year", indicator, etc in the 2015 query (select from dts) instead?  The 2019 version is missing the filter to Saturdays.  
Also is your table actually called `table` or is this an example?  If this is the actual table name, you'll need to double-quote the reserved-words "TABLE" vs table, "DATE" vs date, "YEAR" vs year.

Comment: Your query is fine , it will output Saturdays of 2015 only because you gave 366 days..

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into table (id, date, year, indicator) 
    with dts as (
          select (date '2015-01-01' + rownum - 1) as dt
          from dual
          connect by level <= 366
         )
    select sequ.nextval, dt, extract(year from dt), 'X'
    from dts
    where  to_char(dt, 'fmday') = 'saturday';
```

It basically uses the date-generating query to generate the data for the `insert`.